# Gradle build on GitLab CI: Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory

Tags: docker, gradle, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Using **parallel** *Gradle* jobs on *GitLab CI*:

[image: Parallel Gradle jobs]

I'm receiving following **random** *Gradle* exception:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
> Could not create service of type ResourceSnapshotterCacheService using GradleUserHomeScopeServices.createResourceSnapshotterCacheService().
```

I use a `docker` executor of `gitlab-runner` without any *GitLab CI* caching. I use a *Docker* volume instead with *Gradle* cache pointing to that volume:

```yml
before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=/pipelines/.gradle
```

There is no issue with access rights to the `/pipelines` directory (so it's not duplicity of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30840526/7864001)).

Simple, but annoying workaround to this issue is just to re-trigger the failed job manually - then it passes without any problem. Another workaround could to re-trigger the job automatically via the [retry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#retry) directive.

So, my question is: **What is causing the job failure and how to solve it** (without job re-triggering)**?**

Answer (score 5):

**Root cause:**

After some debugging (switches `--stacktrace` and `--info`), it's obvious that the root cause is that multiple *Docker* containers are sharing one *Gradle* cache on the host machine.

```
Caused by: org.gradle.cache.LockTimeoutException: Timeout waiting to lock file hash cache (/pipelines/.gradle/caches/4.10.2/fileHashes). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
Owner PID: 158
Our PID: 160
Owner Operation: 
Our operation: 
Lock file: /pipelines/.gradle/caches/4.10.2/fileHashes/fileHashes.lock
```

**Solution:**

There is still unsolved *Gradle* bug/feature: [Let multiple containers share downloaded dependencies](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/851). Therefore I (re)implemented proper *Gradle* caching per each involved *GitLab CI* job (so, no shared cache ):

```yml
before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle

rpmClient:
  stage: buildRpm
  script:
  - gradle clientRpm
  cache:
    paths:
    - .gradle/caches
```