# Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory()

Tags: gradle

I am using IntelliJ and am able to build and run my Gradle project via the GUI by pressing the play button, and yet running this command from the terminal

```
./gradlew --stacktrace deploy
```

produces this console output, and the build fails:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
> Could not create service of type PluginResolutionStrategyInternal using BuildScopeServices.createPluginResolutionStrategy().

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceCreationException: Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:816)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:767)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:571)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:628)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:780)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:766)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:571)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:628)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:780)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:766)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:571)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:628)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:295)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:284)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:279)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.doNewInstance(DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.java:179)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.newInstance(DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.java:108)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:40)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceCreationException: Could not create service of type PluginResolutionStrategyInternal using BuildScopeServices.createPluginResolutionStrategy().
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:816)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:767)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:571)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:628)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:780)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:766)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:571)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:628)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:295)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:284)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:279)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.BuildScopeServices.defaultScriptPluginFactory(BuildScopeServices.java:301)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory(BuildScopeServices.java:293)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.invoke(ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:814)
        ... 61 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not generate a proxy class for class org.gradle.plugin.management.internal.DefaultPluginResolutionStrategy.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractClassGenerator.generateUnderLock(AbstractClassGenerator.java:228)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.ClassGeneratorBackedInstantiator.newInstance(ClassGeneratorBackedInstantiator.java:36)
        at org.gradle.plugin.internal.PluginUsePluginServiceRegistry$BuildScopeServices.createPluginResolutionStrategy(PluginUsePluginServiceRegistry.java:106)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.invoke(ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:814)
        ... 79 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BIILjava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/security/ProtectionDomain;)Ljava/lang/Class;
        at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.define(ClassLoaderUtils.java:104)
        at org.gradle.model.internal.asm.AsmClassGenerator.define(AsmClassGenerator.java:58)
        at org.gradle.model.internal.asm.AsmClassGenerator.define(AsmClassGenerator.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AsmBackedClassGenerator$ClassBuilderImpl.generate(AsmBackedClassGenerator.java:967)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractClassGenerator.generateUnderLock(AbstractClassGenerator.java:226)
        ... 88 more
```

Comment: Could be related to this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30840526/gradle-could-not-create-service-of-type-initscripthandler-using-buildscopeservic

Comment: i think im just using java 11, looks like maybe that's the problem `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Worked, was using Java 11, switched to Java 8

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
./gradlew --stacktrace deploy
```

Comment: What if `/usr/libexec/java_home` doesn't exist?

Comment: Maybe Android studio has an internal version of Java its using? Isn't `libexec` where all Java versions are housed?

Comment: If it was, it would be tied to system packages and not Android Studio itself. It's evidently not from Java itself or it would've existed, probably. iDunno. All. The versions are actually stored separately elsewhere, so libexec is probably an abstraction layer (I think)

Answer (score 14):

The issues does come from Java 11, but similarly to the version name issue after the upgrade to Java 10, the issue can be fixed by upgrading Gradle. The issue isn't present in Gradle 5.5, but I'm not sure which version is the earliest to support it. (5.5 is, at the time of writing, the newest version of Gradle)

If you're using the per project Gradle wrapper (with a `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`), all you have to do is change the line containing the distribution URL, and bump the version:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.5-bin.zip
```

Comment: Just ran into the same issue by running a Gradle 4.7 on JVM11. Upgrading Gradle to 5.2.1 was enough to get rid of the error.

Answer (score 5):

### Permissions

I was using a remote Jenkins and the stack trace started similarly to the one in this question but the root cause was failure to create a `.gradle`

dir as the stack trace shows:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Failed to create parent directory '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/APPNAME/workspace/COMPANY/Android/APPNAME/.gradle' when creating directory '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/APPNAME/workspace/COMPANY/Android/APPNAME/.gradle/4.6/fileHashes'
at org.gradle.util.GFileUtils.mkdirs(GFileUtils.java:272)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:58)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:34)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory.doOpen(DefaultCacheFactory.java:92)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory.open(DefaultCacheFactory.java:66)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheRepository$PersistentCacheBuilder.open(DefaultCacheRepository.java:124)
at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CrossBuildFileHashCache.<init>(CrossBuildFileHashCache.java:41)
at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.BuildSessionScopeServices.createCrossBuildFileHashCache(BuildSessionScopeServices.java:194)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
at org.gradle.internal.service.ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.invoke(ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.java:35)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:855)
```

I found out that the dir it was trying to build in was owned by the `root` user but the Jenkins ran with the `jenkins` user. I solved it by `chown`ing the dir to the `jenkins` user.

Comment: Thanks, this was my issue too. This is what happens when I create a new Mac user because my existing one is so bloated (because of Google Chrome).

Answer (score 4):

run this **find ./ -name "*.lock" -type f -delete** in project root directory

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the issue by removing
.gradle/checksums/checksums.lock

and all *.lock files :(

Comment: +1: The wonders of java.. Entirely too much magic all over the place that mostly works, except when it doesn't...

Answer (score 3):

The solution is set old Java version/Java downgrade.

*SOLUTION FOR UBUNTU*

In my laptop I have JAVA installed in **/usr/lib/jvm/**

You can use this command in command line to set temporary **JAVA_HOME**

**`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64`**

or simply update your .bashrc file in home

1. JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/
2. PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
3. export JAVA_HOME**

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue when using **Android Studio** with **libgdx** game library...

In my case I do `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...` and also click on `Invalidate and Restart`  operation and resolved ...

Answer (score 2):

I was in a similar situation. All i had to do was run `chmod 777 .gradle/` on the project directory. You might need to use `sudo`.

Comment: Any reason why this was the answer?  That's not generally a thing one should need to do, or, usually, should do.

Comment: does not work for me. no impact

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, your `gradle` version is too low, if you are `JDK17`, please use `gradle 7.0+`

Answer (score 1):

In my case I just opened up Android Studio and opened the project's folder, then Android Studio updated all the Gradle dependencies automatically. I do not use Android Studio to code (I use VSC), but after this I was able to run the project.

Answer (score 1):

In my IntelliJ *run configuration*, I had just forgot to populate the `Gradle Project` field - building worked after filling that.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Got this error when trying to build a cordova project

cordova run --emulator

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/user/Android/Sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/home/user/Android/Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: /home/user/Android/Sdk

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
> Could not create service of type PluginResolutionStrategyInternal using BuildScopeServices.createPluginResolutionStrategy().
```

the above solution but like this worked for me
ubuntu 18.04.6, npm 7.24.1, cordova 10.0.0, java 8

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
cordova run --emulator
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue recently, there is no specific answers for such issues as this may happen due to many reasons. You can try above solution which is given but I would suggest to check what is the permission given to your .gradle directory which is under your project directory (if you are not able to see .gradle then press Ctrl+H if using ubuntu)

If you working in ubuntu then locate to your project directory say if app name is my-app and then go to my-app and check permission with ll command (LL in small letters)

if above command give root root for .gradle then you need to change permission as ./gradlew clean or ./gradle bootJar may not able to use .gradle

you need to execute

```
sudo chown -R my-system-name:my-system-name .gradle
```

where my-system-name is your machine name so if machine name is manish then

```
sudo chown -R manish:manish .gradle
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using **Gradle 4.3.1**  and this issue comes when I'm running `Jenkinsfile` pipeline **concurrent runs** where a given pipeline is running 
 `parallel` runs of a single Gradle task on N. no. of Gradle projects) in `stages` section.

Removing `parallel` section from the `stages` stage `script` section doesn't result into this --or other weird issues that I have listed in my post below --OR-- when you just run on pipeline run (i.e. non-concurrent runs) of the pipeline.

See here for more about my pipeline job / issues I have faced.

[Jenkins - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Last unit does not have enough valid bits & Gradle error: Task 'null' not found in root project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59797696/jenkins-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-last-unit-does-not-have-enough-val)

Answer (score 0):

- Open your project in show on explorer
- select your project folder then go to property
- then go to security then give access or permission to read, and write
- **basically check your project folder locked or not, if locked (To write) then give permission to write**

Answer (score 0):

The solution(React native) that worked for me. go to the `.gradle` folder and search for all `.lock`  files in the subdirectories and delete them all. after that run the command `gradlew clean` and after that run your project with command `react-native run-android`.

I have also download a `gradle6.6`becasue that was deleted by someone from my system path.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when referencing source code on my Macbook against a GoogleDrive mapped folder.  When I moved my source code to a folder not using GoogleDrive mappings it started working again.  I basically copied my source directory to my home directory, then gradle compiled fine.  Seems some kind a filesystem reference was causing the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it works when switching from java 11 to lower version by running the following command in preoject directory...

export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`

Comment: passing options to the Java runtime should be done using the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable, never using the `JAVA_HOME` one.

Comment: Perhaps that should've been: `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)` - I don't know, I don't have a `/usr/libexec/java_home`