# First time trying Java and Gradle for minecraftforge development; Getting weird errors in Gradle in ScriptPluginFactory and FileHasher

Tags: java, gradle, minecraft, minecraft-forge

The errors appear when running any Gradle task/command.

Errors it gives:

```
* What went wrong:
Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
> Could not create service of type FileHasher using BuildSessionScopeServices.createFileSnapshotter().


* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceCreationException: Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:823)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:774)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:625)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:787)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:773)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:625)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:787)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:773)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:625)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:281)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:276)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.doNewInstance(DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.java:168)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.newInstance(DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.java:98)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.<init>(DefaultRootBuildState.java:45)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildRegistry.addRootBuild(DefaultIncludedBuildRegistry.java:75)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceCreationException: Could not create service of type FileHasher using BuildSessionScopeServices.createFileSnapshotter().
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:823)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:774)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:625)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:787)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:773)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:625)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:787)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:773)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:625)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:787)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:773)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:625)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:281)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:276)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.BuildScopeServices.defaultScriptPluginFactory(BuildScopeServices.java:306)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory(BuildScopeServices.java:298)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.invoke(ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:821)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: Operation not supported
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:40)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:103)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.incrementLockCount(LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:105)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.acquireFileLock(LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:161)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.onStartWork(DefaultCacheAccess.java:368)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:213)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:203)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.newCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:298)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.newCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:57)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.createCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:148)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.createCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:177)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CrossBuildFileHashCache.createCache(CrossBuildFileHashCache.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CachingFileHasher.<init>(CachingFileHasher.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.BuildSessionScopeServices.createFileSnapshotter(BuildSessionScopeServices.java:155)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.invoke(ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:821)
    ... 86 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Operation not supported
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.filelock.LockStateAccess.tryLock(LockStateAccess.java:91)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.filelock.LockFileAccess.tryLockState(LockFileAccess.java:85)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock$4.run(DefaultFileLockManager.java:343)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock$4.run(DefaultFileLockManager.java:337)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$ExponentialBackoff.retryUntil(DefaultFileLockManager.java:405)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.lockStateRegion(DefaultFileLockManager.java:337)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:281)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.<init>(DefaultFileLockManager.java:154)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:100)
    ... 101 more
```

I have tried this through terminal using ./gradlew setupDecompWorkspace and in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition only just importing the gradle.build as project as [this guide](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Creating_Forge_mods) suggests also gives the error.

I have found many questions and tutorials about these errors seperated, but none have helped so far.

Care to help? Can provide info needed. Been stuck with this for whole day.

Comment: Did you do a web search? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53272230/could-not-create-service-of-type-scriptpluginfactory-using-buildscopeservices-cr) came up for me; does that help?