# flutter, then i change folder i got this error here

Tags: flutter

I'm working on a flutter project, but I changed my folder path.

So now when I'm running:

> flutter run

I get this error here:

```
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "/Volumes/free44you/007fred/flutter_apps/flutter_tts/android/gradlew" exited
abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using
BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
> Could not create service of type FileHasher using BuildSessionScopeServices.createFileSnapshotter().

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log
output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
  Command: /Volumes/free44you/007fred/flutter_apps/flutter_tts/android/gradlew app:properties


Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

Can some one help me with this? Thanks :)

**Edit 1/08-2019 20.45**

I'm trying to mount a drev on my computer normal mount works.
Then i'm mount smb into my computer it says the error. below.

Comment: Can you share your app.gradle?

Comment: Sorry, there can i found the app.gradle?

Comment: The file I am referring to is **android/app/build.gradle**.

Comment: you can see the file here (https://people8people.com/flutter_apps.zip)

Comment: I think this will help, this is a similar kind of problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30840526/gradle-could-not-create-service-of-type-initscripthandler-using-buildscopeservic

Comment: Can you help me, with command? to fix it?

Comment: some one can hekp me ?