# * What went wrong: Gradle could not start your build

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build, cannot-find-symbol

- What went wrong:
  **Gradle could not start your build**.
  *- Cannot create service of type TaskExecuter using method ProjectExecutionServices.createTaskExecuter() as there is a problem with parameter #17 of type ReservedFileSystemLocationRegistry.

  - Cannot create service of type ReservedFileSystemLocationRegistry using method ProjectExecutionServices.createReservedFileLocationRegistry() as there is a problem with parameter #1 of type List.
    Could not create service of type ExecutionHistoryStore using ExecutionGradleServices.createExecutionHistoryStore().
    - java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/morakot/Desktop/ecommobile/android/.gradle/6.9/executionHistory/executionHistory.lock (Permission denied)*

Comment: Is it the answer to your question ? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30840526/gradle-could-not-create-service-of-type-initscripthandler-using-buildscopeservic)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.